# How to fix the used key part isn't a string, doesn't support unique prefix keys from prisma migrtion?

Tags: mysql, prisma

I developed locally a MySQL database via prisma and it worked fine until I decided to move out to an external environment, and that's where migration failed:

```
-- DropForeignKey
ALTER TABLE `Invoices` DROP FOREIGN KEY `Invoices_promoCodesId_fkey`;

-- AlterTable
ALTER TABLE `Invoices` DROP COLUMN `promoCodesId`,
    ADD COLUMN `PromoCodesId` INTEGER NULL;

-- AddForeignKey
ALTER TABLE `Invoices` ADD CONSTRAINT `Invoices_PromoCodesId_fkey` FOREIGN KEY (`PromoCodesId`) REFERENCES `PromoCodes`(`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Error:

```
Database error code: 1089

Database error:
Incorrect prefix key; the used key part isn't a string, the used length is longer than the key part, or the storage engine doesn't support unique prefix keys
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Which version of Prisma are you using?

Comment: "prisma": "^4.16.2",
    "@prisma/client": "4.16.2",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I did not find the fix to this issue.

Instead I resolved it squashing the migrations. Don't do this in a shared development environment or on a running production project.

Steps:

- removed the `prisma/migrations` folder
- dropped the local development database entirely
- ran `prisma migrate dev` to create a single migration that represents the actual state
- ran `prisma migrate reset` on problematic production database